# How to pass custom url to SOAP Action in Savon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon

Im using savon 2.0 and the soap action url in the wsdl file is wrong. 
can i manually override the url for this action.

```
client = Savon.client do
      wsdl "http://something.com/someservice/aname.asmx?wsdl"
      convert_request_keys_to :camelcase 
      logger Rails.logger
      log_level :info
      log true
    end 

    response = client.call(:send_actions, message: {

     }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the SOAP action to your client call:

```
response = client.call(
         :send_actions,
         message: {
         },
         soap_action: "my_action_as_string"
)
```